# In Plotly, how to choose a specific color for legend points when using colorscale in group?

Tags: python, plotly

I am plotting a 3d scatter plot in Plotly, similar to the example below. (Though in the actual plot, I have more data groups I'm plotting in various layers, so there's multiple entries in the legend.)  I have to add color from a colorscale to each group of points.  This has the unfortunate side effect of causing the color in the scatter point in the legend to be essentially a random color from this colorscale, rather than a specified one (on the darker end, for example).  To see this effect, change the number in the `_ = nprand.sample(1)` line a few times and you should see the shade of blue in the legend point change.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as nprand

nprand.seed(1)
x = nprand.sample(100)
y = nprand.sample(100)
z = nprand.sample(100)
_ = nprand.sample(1)
color = nprand.sample(100)

trace = go.Scatter3d(x=x,
                     y=y,
                     z=z,
                     name="sample",
                     mode='markers',
                     marker=dict(
                         symbol='circle',
                         size=20,
                         color=color,
                         colorscale="Blues"))

fig = go.Figure(trace)
fig.update_layout(showlegend=True, legend=dict(bordercolor='black', itemwidth=100))
fig.show()
```

**How can I specify a specific color for the point in the legend?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm late on this, but to complement vestland's workaround:
you can copy the first element of your data to the beginning of your array, so the first 2 elements are the same.
Set the color of the first element to any value you like, in order to improve the marker visibility in the legend.
Then the 2nd element will be plotted over the first one, covering it completely, so at the end in your plot you won't see the first element used for the marker.
I hope my suggestions is clear, I tried it that way and works well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Generally, the title and color of the legend elements reflect the properties of the traces they represent. So if you've got a `blue` trace, you'll get a `blue` legend.
In the case you're describing here, the color of the legend varies because the color associated with a specific value varies. And that particucal value seems to be the first element of:

```
fig.data[0].marker.color
```

Example content:

```
array([0.8118587 , 0.87496164, 0.68841325, 0.56949441, 0.16097144,
       0.46688002, 0.34517205, 0.22503996, 0.59251187, 0.31226984,
       0.91630555, 0.90963552, 0.25711829, 0.1108913 , 0.19296273,
       0.49958417, 0.72858567, 0.20819444, 0.24803356, 0.85167187,
       0.41584872, 0.61668507, 0.23366614, 0.10196726, 0.51585702,
       0.47714099, 0.15267164, 0.62180623, 0.54401012, 0.65413735,
       0.14454554,
```

So in your case, you can set the first element to `1` to get a darker color in the legend. Or `0` to get a lighter color in the legend. There are of course plenty of downsides to an approach like this, but this is how it works.

#### Dark `fig.data[0].marker.color[0] = 1`

[image]

#### Light `fig.data[0].marker.color[0] = 0`

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as nprand

nprand.seed(1)
x = nprand.sample(100)
y = nprand.sample(100)
z = nprand.sample(100)
# _ = nprand.sample(1)
color = nprand.sample(100)

trace = go.Scatter3d(x=x,
                     y=y,
                     z=z,
                     name="sample",
                     mode='markers',
                     marker=dict(
                         symbol='circle',
                         size=20,
                         color=color,
                         colorscale="Blues"))

fig = go.Figure(trace)
fig.update_layout(showlegend=True, legend=dict(bordercolor='black', itemwidth=100))
fig.data[0].marker.color[0] = 0

fig.show()
```

Comment: Would this then also change the color of the marker corresponding to the first element of that array?

Comment: @NeutronStar Yes. Not excactly optimal.